# How to write an html from a remote function using writeDump or writeOutput?

Tags: lucee

I am coming from Adobe Coldfusion and I'm trying to debug a component in Lucee by writing values to the output. Normally what I do is:

```
component Sample {
    remote Void function spotCheck() {
    writeDump(1234);
    writeOutput("<br>Test");
    return
}
```

Then hit the page to HTTP://localhost/sample/Sample.cfc?method=spotCheck

But it does not work. I updated the function to have a returnformat="text", but then the output is plain text with HTML tags in its text form.  I tried setting it to "html" instead of text but then I get the error below:

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 20 at column 17: xmlParseEntityRef: no name
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

I'm probably doing it the wrong way and I'm happy to learn the Lucee way of how to easily inspect values of variables inside a component function.
PS: I don't have/use step by step debugger.

Comment: Those are not valid values for `returnFormat`. That attribute only accepts `JSON, plain or WDDX`.  What happens if you try `returnType="xml"` or `returnType="any"`?  Notice that is return **Type** not return **Format** . [Documentation](https://cfdocs.org/cffunction)

Comment: Correct the return format to plain, thanks for pointing that out.  I got weird behavior when there's a mismatch to the return type and what the function actually returns, I get the dump I expect, but with the code error.